# Replace SubQuery with JOIN sql

Tags: sql, database

Is there any way we can replace below query with joins, this hitting the performance while using subquery

Tbl

```
| Col1 |  Col2 |
| ---- | ----- |
| 1    | 100   |
| 2    | 101   |
| 2    | 200   |
| 3    | 205   |
| 4    | 210   |
```

Tbl2

```
| Col1 |  Col2 |
| ---- | ----- |
| 1    | 100   |
| 2    | 101   |
| 2    | 200   |
| 3    | 300   |
| 4    | 210   |
| 5    | 211   |
| 6    | 212   |
```

Expected output

```
| Col1 |  Col2 |
| ---- | ----- |
| 3    | 205   |
```

Query:

```
select 
    t1.col1, t1.col2 
from 
    tb1 t1
where 
    t1.col2 not in (select t2.col2 
                    from tbl2 t2 
                    where t2.col1 = t1.col1)
```

Replace subquery with join

Comment: it would help with a small example of the input/output you have, to get a clear idea of what's happening

Comment: An outer join won't be any more performant (whether you use the keyword or not, the optimizer still has to join the tables) performance will depend on available indexes.

Comment: For questions about performance, please provide the execution plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anti-join. For example:

```
select t1.*
from tb1 t1
left join from tbl2 t2 on t2.col2 = t1.col2
where t2.col2 is null;
```

The following index can improve the query performance:

```
create index ix1 on tbl2 (col2);
```